# Query a subobject's property in a mongodb collection in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to search names in a guest list array that may contain multiple guest objects. This array of objects is stored among other properties in a mongo db collection named "Guests" in my meteor project .

SimpleSchema snippet:

```
guestList: {
    type: [Object],
    label: "Guest List"
}
```

example guest object:

```
var newGuest = [{
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
},
{   
    firstname: "Jane",
    lastName: "Doe"
}];
```

It is being inserted successfully against the SimpleSchema, what I need help with now is how I can search the names if my complete object looks something like this is the collection?

```
{
    guestList: newGuests,
    address: "123 4th St. NE",
    phone: "555-555-5555",
    email: "jon@doe.com"
}
```

Now let's say I have multiple entries with possible multiple guests within each guestList property but I want to get the entry that has the `firstName` of "Jane" in its `guestList` property.

I've tried `Guests.find({ guestList: { firstName : "Jane" } }).fetch();` but I'm not getting any results.

I also tried `Guests.find({guestList[0].firstName: "Jane"}).fetch();` with no results as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is the [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#element-match) query operator. Take a look at how to use it [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-an-array-of-documents) too. I suggest writing your query like so:

```
Guests.find({
    guestList: {
        $elemMatch: {
            firstName: 'Jane'
        }
    }
});
```

The reason why you would not use the first query that you specified is because it is trying to match on a single embedded document rather than on an array of documents. Also, the reason why you would not use the second query that you specified is because it is trying to match only on the first embedded document in an array of documents, but obviously you would want to check all of the embedded documents in an array.

Answer (score 1):

[$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

```
Guests.find({ guestList: { $elemMatch: { firstName: "Jane" }}});
```